# Accessing JSF SelectItem.Label and Value from XHTML without selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, foreach, selectonemenu

I'm struggling with a little internationalization issue in one of my apps.
The story goes like this:

I have a datatable which displays records, and a selectOneMenu in order
to select a column of the dataTable to be filtered for. The selectOne is
fed with SelectItems which are filled according to the actual locale in the 
backing bean on DataRefresh time.

Now, when the user changes the locale the contents of the selectOne stay in the
old locale until the page is rerendered. This is quite logical and expected.

Of course I want that to change.

So I tried writing an own selectOne which uses selectItems which contain
references to languageFile entries in order to be able to change them without
rerendering.

Here's what I tried

```
<select id="j_id5:filterSelector" name="j_id5:filterSelector" size="1"> 
    <c:forEach var="item" items="#{gridBean.filterFields}">
        <option value="#{item.Value}">#{msg[item.Label]}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Sadly JSF tells me the item does not have a Label or Value property, which
I hardly believe. ;)

Does anyone's got an idea how to access thise properties this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with storing the filterfields twice. Once for each language - runtime decission which is rendered. Not a nice one, but it works. Could'nt get the changeListener going...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you should write:

```
#{item.value}
```

instead of `#{item.Value}`, as standard JavaBeans convention is to have `getXyz()` getter for `xyz` property.

Also, why don't you provide a `valueChangeListener` to the UI component for locale selection, and then, inside it, populate the select item labels for that locale. That way you can use standard `f:selectItems` tag.

Comment: thx for the answer, I can access the properties now. My d'oh.

I agree that a valueChangeListener would be the better way
to go. I'm not perfectly sure how to integrate it into my app.

Acually I've got a LanguageSelectioBean which displays two flags
which do change the locale on click, via commandLinks.
--> can command links fire a valueChange event?

Secondy my datatable is a component which I use in several
locations in my app. I need to extend it to make it listen
for valueChanges and requery the language files onValueChange, right?

 thx K

Answer (score 0):

You could also make it so your command links re-render the page so that it automatically does what you need it to. Don't know if this meets your requirements or not. :)